# Unknown option: '--service-worker' creating new angular pwa

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to create a new angular PWA, but when I execute`ng new pwa --service-worker` the system returns **Unknown option: '--service-worker'**

Any idea what's wrong?

- OS: ubuntu gnome 16.04
- Node: v10.16.0
- Npm: 6.9.0

Comment: Have you tried to literally place your error into a Google search?

Comment: Yes with no luck, I found some information but all related to existing projects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `--service-worker` option is only available for the [`ng build` command](https://angular.io/cli/build).

You can generate a PWA by running the regular [`ng new` command](https://angular.io/cli/new) followed by an [`ng add` command](https://angular.io/cli/add).

```
ng new pwa
ng add @angular/pwa --project pwa
```